# Placing a string at the end of multiple formatted functions within a print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello there I am trying to place a % sign at the end of Max and Min PnL with one print function if this is possible, the help would be appreciated. My current output is this `Max PnL:  89.5 Min PnL:  -241.2%`, the % sign is only at the end of the `Min PnL` with the current function below.

```
("Max PnL: ", '{:.1f}'.format(max(bar_positions)), "Min PnL: ", '{:.1f}'.format(min(bar_positions)), end='%')
```

Comment: Does your `bar_positions` is a list?

Comment: What is `end='%'` supposed to mean? That looks like an argument to `print()`, but there's no call to the function.

Comment: @Barmar He might have missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a single format string, and two arguments to `.format()`

```
print("Max PnL: {:.1f}% Min PnL: {:.1f}%".format(max(bar_positions), min(bar_positions)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are only getting the `%` sign at the end of you string because python doesn't understand that these are two separate values that are to be denoted by a % sign at the end of each value, so for that to happen you have a create 2 separate strings and later on merge them together as shown in the below example-**
INFO: Keep in mind if the line is too long for you, you can easily change the separate the strings by making them into variables and then merging them together.

```py
print("Max PnL: " + '{:.1f}'.format(max(bar_positions)) + "%" + " " + "Min PnL: " + '{:.1f}'.format(max(bar_positions)) + "%")
```

Gives the output:

```py
Max PnL: MAX_PNL% Min PnL: MIN_PNL%
```

Hope so this information is useful to you and answers you question!
Happy Coding!

Comment: when I do that it gives me a format error  `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__`

Comment: Hey there @selcukegese  i have made a edit to the most there was a minor bug in the snippet that left as a trace when i was testing your code. The list bar_positions was surrounded  by list brackets so i have removed them so it might fix that minor bug of yours

Comment: Why do all the concatenation instead of a single format string with multiple arguments?

Comment: @Barmar for multiple arguments you need to multiple ```print``` statements to let python understand that these are sperate strings to be denoted by a ```%``` at the end because the ```print``` statement only excepts one ```end``` argument at a time so we have to make two ```print``` statements that will ultimately make the code-snippet 2 lines longer. so that's is why I didn't gave multiple ```end``` arguments.

Comment: You're not using the `end` argument.